# Is it idiomatic when you want the nighttime to pass quickly: "It is not getting morning"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Imagine you have **"toothache"** and you can't stop it, and you understand you have to wait for the morning to be able to go to the dentist.

So you desperately wait throughout the night, and you constantly look at the clock on the wall expecting time is passing quickly. However, every minute you look at the clock, it feels like the time is not passing at all. You look out of the window, it is still night. So can you say:

**"It is not getting morning."** or "**It is not becoming morning."**

Comment: We would probably say, "Morning isn't coming."

Comment: We say *It's getting light* and *It's getting dark*. We don't say  *It's getting morning, It's getting day[light]* or *It's getting night.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, In that case, I can simply say "It is not getting light" or ask a question such as "When will it get light?", can I?

Comment: Yes, both of those suggestions are perfectly idiomatic for the context (except in *speech* almost all native Anglophones would contract ***it is*** to ***it's*** for the first one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks I appreciate your clear answer. By the way, how about the "noon"? We can't say "It is not getting light.", can we?". So, what do we say in the case of "noon"? Should we say "Noon is not coming?

Comment: We *can* say "It's [not] getting light". And we can say "[The] Morning / Evening / Night is coming". But nobody would normally say "Noon is coming", just as we wouldn't normally say "5 o'clock is coming". We say "It's nearly noon", or "It'll soon be 5 o'clock".

Comment: It's not idiomatic to use *getting* with a noun.  It's used with an adjective (or participle used like an adjective), like *getting sick, getting better, getting tired, getting late*, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, "*It is not getting morning*" is grammatically incorrect.

After "getting" in this sense, we need an *adjective phrase*, like "very hot", "much better" or "any lighter". "Morning" is a noun, not an adjective, so the grammar is bad.

"Become" can take a noun phrase after it, so "*It is not becoming morning*" is grammatically correct, and has the meaning you want, but is not natural.

Here are some 100% natural sentences with the meaning you want:

> It's not getting any closer to morning.
> Morning isn't getting any closer.
> Morning just isn't coming.

Answer (score 0):

No.  That is not idiomatic.  Something like, saying nothing because there is nobody to talk to is more idiomatic.

People don't normally speak English unless they have someone to speak to.

If there was someone you might say "It's still night" or "It isn't morning yet".  Your proposed sentences are not idiomatic.    But normally, say nothing.